# Facebook Graph API sharedposts not working as expected

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a website where users authenticate with Facebook and gives my app "user_posts" permission.

I then have a Facebook page that myself as an admin in have given the app "pages_show_list" and "pages_read_engagement" permissions for.

The users then share posts from my Facebook page, and I read who did it with the API (using a page access token).

The problem is "/sharedposts" endpoint on the page post returns no results? Are there more permissions that are needed to read who shared, or do I need to do this another way?

I have tried looking in Graph API documentation and it looks like I could have what is needed for it to work, but apparently not.